# Why does Firefox think I am in Denver?

Tags: firefox, internet, internet-explorer

My work laptop was built in Colorado but I work in Illinois;  When I use Google (paid ads) or MSNBC (local news) Firefox defaults me to Colorado news/ads.

I find MSNBC especially strange since in IE the Local News asks for a zip while Firefox assumes that Colorado is the correct location.

It may be that my IP is reported as being out of Colorado (although SpeedTest.net says the closest location is NJ) but I'm confused by the different behavior between the browsers.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you on WiFi when this happens?  If so, try using a wired connection next time and report back.

Comment: From your question, it sounds like you're using Windows.  Is that correct?  If so, which version?  Does your system clock show the correct time?

Comment: I am on a wired connection running Windows XP and the clock is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is locations sensitive
http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/geolocation/

If your IP shows from Colorado Firefox will assume it true.

you can see where your IP is hailing from at http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/

Comment: http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/ reports me as being in the correct city in Illinois.

Comment: Try reseting your browser data then, it may be saved

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that some cookie(s) were set while it was in Colorado. Try clearing your cookies on both browsers and see if it resets the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I would also check to make sure you don't have firefox configured to go through a proxy server.  That's really the only thing I can think of.